# Xamarin Android: Run task at specific time -->How to run AlarmManager and BroadcastReciver in background?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I want to run a Task (on Android) every day in the morning. I figured out, that I need to use a AlarmManager + Broadcast Reciever. For now, I am sending a notification shortly after App startup to test. It works if the App is active or minimized. If I close it from the recents, it doesn't work anymore.
It seems like I need to use a Service, but I don't really know what part to put in there.
Maybe someone can help :)

This function gets called in the OnCreate Method of the MainActivity:

```
    private void SetAlarm()
    {
        var context = Application.Context;
        var intent = new Intent(context, typeof(AlarmReciever));
        var pending = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);
        var alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService);
        long delay = 10 * 1000;
        alarmManager.SetExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, Java.Lang.JavaSystem.CurrentTimeMillis() + delay, pending);
    }
```

And this is the BroadcastReciever:

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true, Exported = true)]
public class AlarmReciever : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        //Main Task here?
        DependencyService.Get<INotificationManager>().SendNotification("test", "test");
        Toast.MakeText(context, "Test", ToastLength.Long).Show();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Starting from Android oreo and up no more background services are supported. the suggestion from the developer documentation is to use a [foreground service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/foreground-services).

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT Is there really no other option? I don't want to have a notification all day long just because the App needs to run once a day :/

Comment: If you want it to keep working without being killed, you might have to use the foreground service.

Answer (score 0):

**Combine AlarmManager with a Service**

First, you define a class within your application that extends IntentService and defines the OnHandleIntent which describes the work to do when this intent is executed:

```
[Service]
[IntentFilter(new string[] { "package_name" })]
public class TrackingService : IntentService
{
    protected override async void OnHandleIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        await DoSomething();
    }

    protected async Task DoSomething()
    {

    }
}
```

**AlarmReceiver.cs**

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true, Exported = true)]
public class AlarmReciever : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        //call your service here
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, typeof(TrackingService));
        serviceIntent.SetAction(intent.Action);
        context.StartService(serviceIntent);
    }
 }
```

---

**UPDATE** 
Don't test it with a debugger attached to it. I think killing the app, will kill the services as well. Try to build your app in release mode.
 
good luck !

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this also doesn't work. I've tried something similar before :/
I also tried it as a foreground service, but i think the problem is, that the BroadcastReciever gets killed and therefore can't start the Service

Comment: Thanks again, but i already tried that :D I installed it on my phone and checked, that energy saving is turned off for the app. Still not working :/
I then decided to try it with a native java app, and guess what... It works with just the alarmmanger and reciever